# Add service reference to Amazon service fails

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services

Add service reference to Amazon service fails, saying

> "Could not load file or assembly "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0,...' or
>   one or more of it dependencies. The module was expected to contain an
>   assembly manifest."

This is in VS 2008, haven't installed SP1 on this machine yet.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if ASP.NET isn't installed. Go to Add/Remove Windows Components and look under IIS; make sure that ASP.NET is checked (meaning that it's installed.) That should clear up your problem!